# Twillo - how to handle no input on <gather>

Tags: python, flask, twilio, twilio-twiml

I'm building a simple Twillo (programmable voice) application using Python flask and the [twillo-python helper library](https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/python).  There are several steps to the voice menu, but the first asks the caller to enter a pin number.

I am trying to working out what the best practice to deal with no caller input from a TwiML `<Gather>` verb in a DRY way.  I've made a function `process_no_input_response` which receives and returns a twllio `resp` object with appropriate `<Say>` messages depending on if the maximum number of allowed retries has been reached. Code example is below.

Is there a better way to handle these scenarios?  Keen for any advice or feedback on this code.

```
def process_no_input_response(resp, endpoint, num_retries_allowed=3):
    """Handle cases where the caller does not respond to a `gather` command.
       Determines whether to output a 'please try again' message, or redirect 
       to the hand up process

    Inputs:
      resp -- A Twillo resp object
      endpoint -- the Flask endpoint
      num_retries_allowed -- Number of allowed tries before redirecting to 
        the hang up process

    Returns:
      Twillo resp object, with appropriate ('please try again' or redirect) syntax
    """

    # Add initial caller message
    resp.say("Sorry, I did not hear a response.")

    session['num_retries_allowed'] = num_retries_allowed

    # Increment number of attempts
    if endpoint in session:
        session[endpoint] += 1
    else:
        session[endpoint] = 1

    if session[endpoint] >= num_retries_allowed:
        # Reached maximum number of retries, so redirect to a message before hanging up
        resp.redirect(url=url_for('bye'))
    else:
        # Allow user to try again
        resp.say("Please try again.")
        resp.redirect(url=url_for(endpoint))

    return resp

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def step_one():
    """Entry point to respond to incoming requests."""

    resp = twilio.twiml.Response()
    with resp.gather(numDigits=6, action="/post_step_one_logic", method="POST") as gather:
        gather.say("Hello. Welcome to my amazing telephone app! Please enter your pin.")

    return str(process_no_input_response(resp, request.endpoint))    

@app.route('/bye', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def bye():
    """Hangup after a number of failed input attempts."""

    resp = twilio.twiml.Response()
    resp.say("You have reached the maximum number of retries allowed. 
       Please hang up and try calling again.")
    resp.hangup()

    return str(resp)
```

Answer (score 2):

I actually found a tidier way to do this, without the need for a helper function. In this approach, all the timeout logic (i.e. 'Please try again' or hang up) in a `/timeout` endpoint.

This appears to be the implied suggestion for timeouts, having seen the example in the [Advanced use section of the Twillo documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/gather#hints).

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def step_one():
    """Entry point to respond to incoming requests."""

    resp = twilio.twiml.Response()
    with resp.gather(numDigits=6, action="/post_step_one_logic", method="POST") as gather:
        gather.say("Hello. Welcome to my amazing telephone app! Please enter your pin.")
    resp.redirect(url=url_for('timeout', source=request.endpoint))

    return str(resp)


@app.route('/timeout', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def timeout():
    """Determines whether to output a 'please try again' message, or if they
       should be cut off after a number of (i.e. 3) failed input attempts.
       Should include 'source' as part of the GET payload.
    """

    # Get source of the timeout
    source = request.args.get('source')

    # Add initial caller message
    resp = twilio.twiml.Response()
    resp.say("Sorry, I did not hear a response.")

    # Increment number of attempts
    if source in session:
        session[source] += 1
    else:
        session[source] = 1

    # Logic to determine if user should be cut off, or given another chance
    if session[source] >= 3:
        # Reached maximum number of retries, so redirect to a message before hanging up
        resp.say("""
            You have reached the maximum number of retries allowed. Please hang up 
            and try calling again.
            """)
        resp.hangup()
    else:
        # Allow user to try again
        resp.say("Please try again.")
        resp.redirect(url=url_for(source))

    return str(resp)
```

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

That seems like a reasonable way to build this response. Redirecting round to play the [`<Gather>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/gather) again until you reach a number of attempts is a great way of dealing with this situation (and one I can't think of a a better way to deal with right now). Indeed, it is effectively the solution suggested in the [Advanced use section of the documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/gather#hints).

Comment: Thanks so much for your quick response @philnash - I think I've found a more elegant and tidier way to do it, and have posted a separate answer.